# Problem populating GridView from assets

Tags: android, gridview, bufferedinputstream

I am trying to populate Android GridView with inflated view, view has ImageView and TextView which is populate from ArrayList of data.

Fverything is fine but, my first 7 items are repeating, as I scroll the grid.

```
namCont.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
```

My code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return kat.namirnice.size();

    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View view;
        ImageView imageView = null;

        if (convertView == null) 
        { 
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.nam_item,null);
            try 
            {
                TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tekst);

                imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.slika);

                textView.setText(kat.namirnice.get(position).naziv);

                Log.i(TAG, "\n position: " + position);
                buf = new BufferedInputStream((assetManager.open("images/" + activKat_int + "/" + position + ".png")));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
                buf.close();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            view = convertView;
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The Views in a ListView are recycled. So eventually, I guess when you get to position 8 it goes to recycle its first view, and in your code the block `view = convertView;` all you are doing is returning the existing recycled view.

Instead you need to do this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.nam_item,
                    null);
        }
        try {
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tekst);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.slika);
            textView.setText(kat.namirnice.get(position).naziv);
            Log.i(TAG, "\n position: " + position);
            buf = new BufferedInputStream((assetManager.open("images/"
                    + activKat_int + "/" + position + ".png")));
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```