# how to create an android frame-by-frame animation from images in assets folder?

Tags: android, animation, assets

I am a beginner in android, and I want to create a frame-by-frame animation that its images are placed in assets folder. Previously I created a simple animation which the images were placed in res/drawable folder. I also placed a gyro_animation.xml file in that folder. In this sample I created an animation in my activity as it follows:

```
    ImageView gyroView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gyro);
    gyroView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gyro_animation));
    final AnimationDrawable gyroAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) gyroView.getBackground();
```

now for creating an animation that its images are resided in assets folder what should I do ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create an animation-list drawable in your resources folder, and set it as background to your `ImageView`. You can see a detailed explenation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080024/display-an-animated-png-image-to-my-layout-in-android-using-xml).

Comment: thanks for reply, I know it, but when the images are in assets folder what should I do ?? I think it is not possible to perform like this manner, because assets folder's files haven't ID and cant be accessed like this.

Comment: Move your images in the resources folder. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: I want to create an app like Talking tom.there are many animation and many images. If I move them in resource folder Out of Memory Exception Occurs.

Comment: Also I checked Talking Tom apk and saw that the images are in asset folder. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AnimationDrawable` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) directly.

You will have to load images in the assets folder, [make `BitmapDrawables` of of them like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204094/problem-populating-gridview-from-assets) and then use [`AnimationDrawable.addFrame`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#addFrame%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int%29) on a `new AnimationDrawable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Frame by frame animation load from images in assets folder
[click here](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-make-a-frame-animation-with-a-character-sprite-in-android/)